# get thumbnail path into wordpress query result

Tags: json, wordpress, get, posts

I have a basic ajax response script that returns worpress posts as json.

I want to additionally get the thumbnail path as well and include that in JSON, i believe this is a meta query. How would I incoprate the meta query into the get_posts function.

(Note :The thumbnail path will be of the featured image of the post)

the script i have is below (It works as well):

```
<?php 

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
header('Content-type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode(get_posts(array(
'posts_per_page' => 7,'post__in' => array(1,7))));


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use query_posts e.g.

```
    json_arr =  array();

        $args = array(
         'posts_per_page' => 7,
         'post__in' => array(1,7)

        );
    query_posts($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

     //add bits and bobs to json array e.g.
    $json_arr[] = $post; 

    }
echo json_encode($json_arr);
```

You can add what you want to the json array rather than adding the whole post. I haven't tested this but this is how I would approach it.

This gets the path of the thumbnail:

```
 $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
 $path  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id );
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there will be some magic query function which will get extra infos about posts. And wanted to avoid using the loop, but looks like i have to use the loop method you have given.